# Multiline comments in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: comments, inno-setup, pascalscript

According to [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_basic_syntax.htm#:%7E:text=The%20multiline%20comments%20are%20enclosed,brackets%20%7B%20...%20%7D.) it states:

> #Comments
> The **multiline** comments are enclosed within curly brackets and
> asterisks as `(* ... *)`. Pascal allows **single-line** comment enclosed
> within curly brackets `{ ... }`.
>
> ```pascal
> (* This is a multi-line comments
>    and it will span multiple lines. *)
>
> { This is a single line comment in pascal }
> ```

I had been using `{ ... }` with multiple lines. It seems OK in Inno Setup `Code` section. But is it bad syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That article is wrong. Both `(* ... *)` and `{ ... }` are multi-line comments and they are equivalent.

A single line comment in Pascal (Script) starts with `//`:

```pascal
// Single line comment
```

See https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse2.html